# Jquery .val() gets the correct value but doesn't pass it to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a string or 'url' from selected form values.  I don't want to process the form anywhere, its just to piece together a string from a set of options.

I have a select class

```
<div id="colorselect">
<select class="selectpicker" data-size="5">
                <option>red</option>
                <option>blue</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

The default is "red" and when I change to "blue" I can see it changes by typing in the console...

```
$( "#colorselect.select option:selected" ).val();
```

which gives me

```
"blue"
```

I then set the .val() as a variable

```
var urlColor = $( "#colorselect.select option:selected" ).val();

and pass to a function

function urlGenerator(urlColor){
    var url = 'http://localhost/pixacca/' + urlColor;

// Passes the url into the textarea

    $( "#output" ).val(url);
}
```

When I click the button it returns red instead of blue?

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="process" href="#" role="button">Generate</a>

<div class="output"></div>

$("#process").click( function() {
    urlGenerator(urlColor)
 });
```

Comment: get  the selected value whenever needed instead of storing it in a variable.  or add a change listener to set the value of selected item.

Comment: When you run the code thats sets the variable on load, `red` is selected. You don't retrieve the value *after* the selection has been changed.

Comment: add a change listener to update the global variable value. `var urlColor = 'blue'; // default value $('#colorselect.select').change(function(){urlColor=$('#colorselect.select option:selected').val();});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `$( "#colorselect.select option:selected" ).val()` *inside* the function:

```
function urlGenerator(){
    var url = 'http://localhost/pixacca/' + $( "#colorselect.select option:selected" ).val();
    $( "#output" ).val(url);
}
```

If you assign some value to a variable, the variable doesn’t automatically update itself.

In other words,

```
var urlColor = $( "#colorselect.select option:selected" ).val();
```

means: declare variable `urlColor`, then assign to it whatever `$( "#colorselect.select option:selected" ).val()` *currently* returns (even if the return value may change some time later).

---

Furthermore, the function can be reduced to

```
function urlGenerator(){
    $('#output').val('http://localhost/pixacca/'+$('#colorselect select').val());
}
```

as the `value` property of a `select` element represents the `value` of the selected `option`.

Comment: Also the `.select` on `#colorselect.select` is kinda pointless, but obviously that wasn't the issue.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That’s true and there are some other optimizations, e.g. the selector can actually be reduced to `$("#colorselect select")` as the `value` of the select element is always the one of the selected option. Also, the variable `url` is useless: the whole thing could just be `$('#output').val('http://…'+$('#colorselect select').val());`.

Comment: thankyou very much. I will also make the corrections to the unnecessary bits of code :)